# Apache commons-net FTP - uploading file to Secure FTP IIS

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I'm trying to upload large file (>100Mb) using Apache commons-net FTP library to Secure FTP Server IIS.

Here is my code:

```
try{
ftpClient = new FTPSClient("TLS", false);
        this.ftpClient.setDataTimeout(6000000);
        this.ftpClient.setConnectTimeout(6000000);
        ftpClient.connect(host, port);
        ftpClient.login(userName, password);
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
         if (ftpClient.getReplyCode() == 230){
               ftpClient.sendCommand("OPTS UTF8 ON");
               ftpClient.execPBSZ(0);
               ftpClient.execPROT("P");
         else{
             throw new Exception("connection failed.....");}
         ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        InputStream is= new FileInputStream("C:\\movie.avi");
         ftpClient.setUseEPSVwithIPv4(true);
             ftpClient.storeFile(remotePath, is);
         is.close();
       }
         catch (SocketException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It fails to upload files larger then 19Mb. storeFile methods throws `IOException` with empty StackTrace. You can see below `IOException` variables:

```
   e    CopyStreamException  (id=39)    
    cause   CopyStreamException  (id=39)    
    detailMessage   "IOException caught while copying." (id=45) 
    ioException SocketException  (id=46)    
        cause   SocketException  (id=46)    
        detailMessage   "Connection reset by peer: socket write error" (id=50)  
        stackTrace  null    
    stackTrace  null    
    totalBytesTransferred   19084288
```

Actually it behaves the following way:

1) when I'm starting upload, zero size file created, while I'm uploading file size is still zero and when the exception occurs, this empty file removed by FTP.

2) funny thing is that FileZila fails to upload these files as well, but its limit size is 70Mb.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Do FileZilla and your code fail after the same amount of time, approximately? Have you successfully uploaded a larger file than this using other means (a command line FTP client, whatever)?

Comment: I've tried to play with time out and It looks like it fails as soon as it reaches its limit, in my case it is 19 Mb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. Sad by true, the problem caused by firewall, which closed Data port after 5 minutes time out.